# Linear probing not working for collision

Tags: c, hashtable, linear-probing

I am making a hash table based on reg no. The insertion function is working fine but the search and deletion doesn't work in case of collision. It's not doing anything at all. There aren't any compilation errors either. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int size=4;
struct students
{
    char name[50];
    int regno;
    int age;
    char city[50];
}stud[4];

void insertion()
{
    int reg,k,i;
    printf("\nenter the student details you want to insert:\n");
    printf("\nenter regno: ");
    scanf("%d",&reg);
    k=reg%size;
    if (stud[k].regno==0)
    {
        stud[k].regno=reg;
        printf("\nenter name: ");
        scanf("%s",&stud[k].name);
        printf("\nenter age: ");
        scanf("%d",&stud[k].age);
        printf("\nenter city: ");
        scanf("%s",&stud[k].city);
    }

    else
    {
        for(i=k+1;i<size;i++)
        {
            if (stud[i].regno==0)
            {
                stud[i].regno=reg;
                printf("\nenter name: ");
                scanf("%s",&stud[i].name);
                printf("\nenter age: ");
                scanf("%d",&stud[i].age);
                printf("\nenter city: ");
                scanf("%s",&stud[i].city);
                break;
            }
            else
                for(i=0;i<k;i++)
                {
                    if (stud[i].regno==0)
                    {

                        stud[i].regno=reg;
                        printf("\nenter name: ");
                        scanf("%s",&stud[i].name);
                        printf("\nenter age: ");
                        scanf("%d",&stud[i].age);
                        printf("\nenter city: ");
                        scanf("%s",&stud[i].city);
                        break;
                    }

                }

        }

    }
}

void deletion()
{
    int reg, k;
    int f=0;
    printf("\nenter the student reg no you want to delete");
    scanf("%d",&reg);
    k=reg%size;
    if(stud[k].regno==0)
    {
        printf("\nIt is empty");
    }

    else if(stud[k].regno==reg)
    {
        printf("The removed student is %d",stud[k].regno);
        stud[k].regno=0;
        stud[k].name[0]='\0';
        stud[k].age=0;
        stud[k].city[0]='\0';
        printf("\n\n");

    }

    else
    {   
        int i;
        for (i=k+1;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(stud[k].regno==reg)
            {
                printf("The removed student is %d",stud[k].regno);
                stud[k].regno=0;
                stud[k].name[0]='\0';
                stud[k].age=0;
                stud[k].city[0]='\0';
                printf("\n\n");
                f=1;
                break;
            }

        }

        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            if (stud[i].regno==reg)
            {
                printf("The removed student is %d",stud[k].regno);
                stud[k].regno=0;
                stud[k].name[0]='\0';
                stud[k].age=0;
                stud[k].city[0]='\0';
                printf("\n\n");
                f=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (f==1)
    {
        printf("\nIt is not present");
    }
}


void search()
{
    int reg, k;
    int f=0;
    printf("\nenter the student reg no you want to search");
    scanf("%d",&reg);
    k=reg%size;
    if(stud[k].regno==0)
    {
        printf("\nIt is empty");
    }

    else if(stud[k].regno==reg)
    {
        printf("The student found is: \n");
        printf("\nreg no: %d",stud[k].regno);
        printf("\nname: %s",stud[k].name);
        printf("\nage: %d",stud[k].age);
        printf("\ncity: %s",stud[k].city);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    else
    {
        int i;
        for (i=k+1;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(stud[k].regno==reg)
            {
                printf("The student found is: \n");
                printf("\nreg no: %d",stud[k].regno);
                printf("\nname: %s",stud[k].name);
                printf("\nage: %d",stud[k].age);
                printf("\ncity: %s",stud[k].city);
                printf("\n\n");
                f=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            if (stud[i].regno==reg)
            {
                printf("The student found is: \n");
                printf("\nreg no: %d",stud[k].regno);
                printf("\nname: %s",stud[k].name);
                printf("\nage: %d",stud[k].age);
                printf("\ncity: %s",stud[k].city);
                printf("\n\n");
                f=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (f==1)
        {
            printf("\nIt is not present");
        }
    }
}

void display()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("\nreg no: %d",stud[i].regno);
        printf("\nname: %s",stud[i].name);
        printf("\nage: %d",stud[i].age);
        printf("\ncity: %s",stud[i].city);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i,c;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        stud[i].regno=0;
        stud[i].name[0]='\0';
        stud[i].age=0;
        stud[i].city[0]='\0';
    }

    do {
        printf (" Enter 1 for insert \n");
        printf (" Enter 2 for deletion \n");
        printf (" Enter 3 for search \n");
        printf (" Enter 4 for display \n");
        scanf ("%d", &c);
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1: insertion();
                break;
            case 2: deletion();
                break;
            case 3: search();
                break;
            case 4: display();
        }
    } while(c>0 && c<=4);
}
```

Comment: I doubt you intended to nest your for loops in that monstrosity called `insertion`, but that's exactly what you did, and in so doing, you cycle `i`. The days of line editing on a decwriter are long-gone. indent, and properly brace, your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your inner loops.

```
        else
            for(i=0;i<k;i++)
            {
```

`i` is already in use, so you must use a new variable:

```
        else
            for(int j=i+1;j<k;j++)
            {
```

This error is present in many places.

I believe your code can be "compressed". I believey our `if..else { for..if..else { for..if` can be made into a single loop that, starting from `reg%size` searches for the first empty entry. That would make an elegant solution.

Comment: In the question, it was given that I have to do so using structures. Incase reg%size gives the same value (which I am referring to as collision), I want the key value (reg%size) to shift to the next empty location and the details to be stored there. I don't understand why you said it'll overwrite. Structures can store information, and I declared 4 records using `stud[4]` I am sorry for the indentation, I am new to programming. Will keep in mind for future questions :)

Comment: What you describe is not hashing. Of course you use structures, but you store them in the linked lists of the buckets. And linked list itself is a struct, of course More than enough structs to satisfy your teacher!

Comment: According to what we have been taught, there are 2 ways to implement hash table 1) Using linked list, 2) array implementation. I am trying to use array implementation in my code. I agree your method sounds much better but I have been asked to solve this problem in this way only. Can you please tell me how I can fix this code?

Comment: Ashrav, my apologies. I didn't see the linear probing and had forgotten about it.. Though I found the bug. See revised answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. And can you tell me how to do the same thing for quadratic probing?

Comment: The basic way to implement quadratic probing is 1) google; 2) write the algorithm 3) debug it. Your work, your learning, and probably your homework.